# How to Transfer with minimum Balance Fee

Tags: java, user-interface, netbeans

Hello I'm trying to make my program run so that when you are transferring money a transfer fee of $2.0 is ONLY applied to accounts with a balance less than $10,000.

The issue I am having is that my code is charging me a transfer fee regardless of my balance. If I have a balance of $5,000,000 and I transfer $9,999 dollars it charges me a transfer fee of 2.0.

If I try to transfer > $10,000 there is NO transfer fee. Please spot my error. Thank you so much.

There are 5 classes so i'm going to paste all the relevant information below.

```
// CLASS 1 
public class AccountConstants {
private final double CHECKING_BALANCE_THRESHOLD = 10000;
private final double TRANSFER_FEE = 2.0;

public double getFee(double amount){
    if (amount < CHECKING_BALANCE_THRESHOLD){
        return TRANSFER_FEE;
    }
    return 0.0;
}

public class CheckingAccount extends Account{
public CheckingAccount(String number, String name, GregorianCalendar 
openDate, double balance){
    super(number,name,openDate,balance);
}


//CLASS 2
    @override   
    public int transferTo(Account account, double amount) {
    AccountConstants ac = new AccountConstants();
    double fee = ac.getFee(amount);
    if (this.getBalance() < amount)
        return -2;
    else if (this.getBalance() < (amount+fee))
        return -1;
    else if (this.getBalance()>=(amount+fee)&& fee==2.0){
       this.setBalance(-(amount+fee));
       account.setBalance(amount);
       return 1;
    }
    else
        this.setBalance(-amount);
        account.setBalance(amount);
        return 0;
}

//CLASS 3 
if (result == 0)
{
    au.setBalance(jComboBox1.getSelectedIndex(), 
    accounts.getBalance());
    au.setBalance(index, accounts_to.getBalance());
    NumberFormat defaultFormat = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();                     
    txtBalance.setText(defaultFormat.format(accounts.getBalance()));
    au.updateFile(au.getAccountNumber(index), au.getOpenDate(index),
    au.getCustomerName(index), au.getBalance(index));
    index = jComboBox1.getSelectedIndex();
    au.updateFile(au.getAccountNumber(index), au.getOpenDate(index), au.getCustomerName(index), au.getBalance(index));
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, defaultFormat.format(amount)+" was transfered to "+accountNumber,"Transfer successful", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
}

else if (result == 1)
{
    au.setBalance(jComboBox1.getSelectedIndex(), accounts.getBalance());
    au.setBalance(index, accounts_to.getBalance());
    NumberFormat defaultFormat = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();                 
    txtBalance.setText(defaultFormat.format(accounts.getBalance()));
    au.updateFile(au.getAccountNumber(index), au.getOpenDate(index),au.getCustomerName(index), au.getBalance(index));
    index = jComboBox1.getSelectedIndex();
    au.updateFile(au.getAccountNumber(index), au.getOpenDate(index), au.getCustomerName(index), au.getBalance(index));
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, defaultFormat.format(amount)+" was transfered to "+accountNumber+"\n$2.0 transfer fee was applied", "Transfer successful", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ugg, can you please format the code properly? It gave me a sore head. But anyway:

```
double fee = ac.getFee(amount);
```

Should be:

```
double fee = ac.getFee(this.getBalance());
```

As the fee is calculated on the balance, not on the amount transferred.

Also, this is not causing a problem right now, but:

```
else
    this.setBalance(-amount);
    account.setBalance(amount);
    return 0;
```

Should be:

```
else
{
    this.setBalance(-amount);
    account.setBalance(amount);
    return 0;
}
```

Also, returning mysterious values of `-2` to `1` doesn't help with understandability of the code.

Comment: Sorry new to this and Thank You!

Comment: Teacher made us pick those values but yes thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You are sending the amount to the `getFee` function instead of the balance.

Change:

```
double fee = ac.getFee(amount);
```

To:

```
double fee = ac.getFee(this.getBalance());
```

Also this is bad:

```
else if (this.getBalance()>=(amount+fee)&& fee==2.0){
```

You should change it to:

```
else if (this.getBalance()>=(amount+fee)&& fee==TRANSFER_FEE){
```

Or even better:

```
else if (this.getBalance()>=(amount+fee)&& fee > 0.0){
```

Comment: appreciate the help!